# ruby on rails active item in multilevel menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, menu

What is the best approach of dealing with **class="active"** problems in Rails?
I've found how to deal with this for single links, but when classes has to be set to "active" in different parts of the template, how do one deal with this?
Here is my code:

```
module AdminHelper
    def nav_link(link_text, link_path)
        class_name = current_page?(link_path) ? 'active' : nil
        content_tag(:li) do
            link_to link_text, link_path, :class => class_name
        end
    end

    def active_section(section)
        request.fullpath.start_with?(section)
    end
end
```

And in the layout holding the menu:

```
<% if active_section('/superadmin') %>
<li class="active">
<% else %>
<li>
<% end %>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-asterisk fa-fw"></i> Superadmin <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
        <%= nav_link 'Add Account', superadmin_new_account_path %>
        <%= nav_link 'List Accounts', superadmin_list_accounts_path %>
    </ul>
</li>
```

That is, I need to check if I am at a specific part of the url structure, and outputting the **li class="active"** in case of that. Otherwise just outputting the **li** element without class. I am using a menu; MetisMenu and needs to set this class so correct section is expanded.

My code works but it feels horrible wrong way to do it.
Would be really happy if someone can give a hint on how to do this the right way!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [simple-navigation](https://github.com/codeplant/simple-navigation) gem

Answer (score 0):

Not to be 'that guy', but have you looked into [HAML](http://haml.info)? It makes doing conditional classing a ton easier. It also reads/looks much cleaner. i.e.

`%li{:class => ("active" if active_section('/superadmin'))}`